# Can you pass data from HttpModule to IIS hosted WCF without aspNetCompatibility enabled

Tags: wcf, httpmodule

I currently have a HttpModule that generates a unique ID per external client request, appends it to the IIS log, and adds it to the HttpContext.Items collection in order to pass in on the thw web service.

I am currently replacing the web service with a WCF service (still hosted under IIS).  I can successfully do the same process by enabling AspNet compatibility, but I would prefer not to.  Is there any way to pass data from a HttpModule to say the OperationContext of the WCF service without enabling AspNet compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

This is what MSDN has to say,
HttpModule extensibility: The WCF hosting infrastructure intercepts WCF requests when the PostAuthenticateRequest event is raised and does not return processing to the ASP.NET HTTP pipeline. Modules that are coded to intercept requests at later stages of the pipeline do not intercept WCF requests. 
I suggest you go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) MSDN documentation completely to understand how ASP.Net and WCF coexist

Comment: I am currently generating my ID in BeginRequest, which still occurs before the call is intercepted.

Comment: Sorry i missed the sharing the uniqueid part post the module handling. Adding http header could be something that you can look into, but it seems more like an hack.http://forums.asp.net/p/979853/1250479.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that approach and it is unsuccessful since I'm not a web-app.